# Acronym after the title and DATE.NOW

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This may be a simple question but what is the best way to get the first letter of each word in the title (in Index.csshtml)?

The Index.csshtml looks like:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
    
                @*Here... I want the
            acronym of “laugh out loud” for example which is LOL.*@
    
    
    
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Author)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pages)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RunTimeMinutes)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsBorrowable)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Borrower)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BorrowDate)
    
    
       @*Here... I want to put the borrow date*@
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Type)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.CategoryName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
```

My second question is, how do I get the borrow date? As you can see above I've commented that under "BorrowDate".

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string by space, then take first letters and join them.

```
var words = item.Title.Split(' ');

var firstLetters = words.Select(w=> w.First());

var result = string.Concat(firstLetters).ToUpper();
```

inline:

```
var result = string.Concat(item.Title.Split(' ').Select(w => w.First())).ToUpper();
```

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
    
                @(string.Concat(item.Title.Split(' ').Select(w => w.First())).ToUpper())
      
    
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Author)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pages)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RunTimeMinutes)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsBorrowable)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Borrower)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BorrowDate)
    
    
       @*Here... I want to put the borrow date*@
                @item.BorrowDate
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Type)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.CategoryName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
}
```

Comment: it did not work. When I rund the program it only shows "laugh out loud". What I want to show is "laugh out loud(lol)". Do you have other solutions?

Comment: Where should I put: var words = item.Title.Split(' ');

var firstLetters = words.Select(w=> w.First());

var result = firstLetters.ToString().ToUpper();?? In the Controller or Index.csshtml??

Comment: I get the following when i run the program: SYSTEM.LINQ.ENUMERABLE+WHERESELECTARRAYITERATOR`2[SYSTEM.STRING,SYSTEM.CHAR]

Comment: you can put it here in the .cshtml;

Comment: like this:    @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                var words = item.Title.Split(' ');

                var firstLetters = words.Select(w => w.First());

                var result = firstLetters.ToString().ToUpper();

            }

            @(item.Title.Split(' ').Select(w => w.First()).ToString().ToUpper())

?

Comment: With that when I run the program i get this error: SYSTEM.LINQ.ENUMERABLE+WHERESELECTARRAYITERATOR`2[SYSTEM.STRING,SYSTEM.CHAR] . How can i solve it?